# Data driven page in ArcGIS - export to PDF - page name

Tags: arcgis-desktop, data-driven-pages

I am working with data driven pages. In data driven object attributes I have one attribute column with page order (index), another with page name.

Is there a way to get file name like: `%Page order%_Some-text_%Page index%.pdf`?

[image: Export Map menu]

Comment: Have you considered creating another field for page name that combines your other fields?

Comment: It's kind of workaround. Page name is fixed for certain extent but index is connected to way PDF's are related between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I have added "CURRENT" to arcpy.mapping.MapDocument because it caused error.
2. strOutpath, FIELD1 and FIELD2 can be modified.
3. field1 & 2 are fields from layer attribute table that is used for DDP.
4. Both fields MUST be text field.

```
     import arcpy
        strOutpath = "C:/temp/"
        mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
        for pageNum in range(1, mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount + 1):
         mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID = pageNum
         pageorder = mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageRow.FIELD1
         pageindex = mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageRow.FIELD2
         pdfname = pageorder + pageindex + ".pdf"     
         arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd, strOutpath  + pdfname)
        del mxd
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write a python script to do what you want. Here is a sample (I haven't tested it, but I've done these many times.)
Page_order is the attribute name in the DDP index layer
Page_index is the other attribute with the name.

```
import arcpy
strOutpath = "C:/Temp/"
try:
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(strPath + strMXD + ".mxd")
    for pageNum in range(1, mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageCount + 1):
        mxd.dataDrivenPages.currentPageID = pageNum
        pageorder = mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageRow.Page_order
        pageindex = mxd.dataDrivenPages.pageRow.Page_index
        pdfname = pageorder + "_Some-text_" + pageindex + ".pdf"      
        arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF(mxd, strOutpath  + pdfname)
    del mxd

except:
    print "An error has occurred"
```